# Autowired XStreamMarshaller Loses unknownFieldsToIgnore Setting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, xstream

We have an XStreamMarshaller defined as an @Bean in a Spring Boot application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...

    @Bean
    public XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller() {
        XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        Class<?>[] annotatedClasses = { MyAnnotatedClass.class };
        xStreamMarshaller.setAnnotatedClasses(annotatedClasses);
        NameCoder nameCoder = new XmlFriendlyNameCoder();
        xStreamMarshaller.setNameCoder(nameCoder);
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().ignoreUnknownElements();

        return xStreamMarshaller;
    }
}
```

It is autowired into a JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyApplication.class })
public class MyAnnotatedClassTest {
    @Autowired
    private XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller;

    // ...
}
```

When examining it in the debugger, when it is constructed, `xStreamMarshaller.xstream.fieldAliasingMapper.unknownFieldsToIgnore = [.*]`

When examining the autowired instance (which has the same object id), `xStreamMarshaller.xstream.fieldAliasingMapper.unknownFieldsToIgnore = []`

Why does it lose the `unknownFieldsToIgnore` setting and how can it be forced to keep that setting?

**EDIT:**

Per @indyaah, I've moved the bean definition into:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.application" })
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...

    @Bean
    public XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller() {
        XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        Class<?>[] annotatedClasses = { MyAnnotatedClass.class };
        xStreamMarshaller.setAnnotatedClasses(annotatedClasses);
        NameCoder nameCoder = new XmlFriendlyNameCoder();
        xStreamMarshaller.setNameCoder(nameCoder);
        xStreamMarshaller.getXStream().ignoreUnknownElements();

        return xStreamMarshaller;
    }
}
```

and made my Spring Boot Application file very thin:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This still has the same behavior as before the refactoring.

Comment: Might be irrelevant but @SpringBootApplication on WebMvcConfigurerAdapter extension doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: @indyaah : The @ SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using @ Configuration, @ EnableAutoConfiguration and @ ComponentScan with their default attributes.

Comment: @K139: That I understand, what I was trying to say was that somewhere AutoConfig might be messing up with configure(..) calls on WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. But as I said I am not that sure. Just wanted to give one possible direction. :)

Comment: OK. I've moved the bean definitions into a new class, MvcConfiguration which extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and is annotated with Configuration, EnableWebMvc, and ComponentScan. I've removed the extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter from MyApplication. Same behavior.